# C# equivalent code for Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

How can I convert the below code to C#? 
I have an XML string where in I need to find the attribute name and at the same time check whether there is a parent node with "alias".

```
$atts = $xml.GetElementsByTagName('attribute');
foreach($att in $atts)
{
    if($att.ParentNode.HasAttribute('alias'))
    {
        $attName = $att.ParentNode.GetAttribute('alias') + "." + $att.name
        Write-Output $att.ParentNode.GetAttribute('alias') + "." + $att.name
    }
    else
    {
        $attName = $att.name
        Write-Output $att.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is not a free code converting service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Xml;

    class XmlTest
    {
        public static void yourTest()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load("yourXmlPath.xml");

            // It is recommended that you use the XmlNode.SelectNodes or XmlNode.SelectSingleNode method instead of the GetElementsByTagName method.
            XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("attribute");

            foreach(XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
            {
                if (xmlNode.ParentNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("alias") != null)
                {
                    string attributeName = xmlNode.ParentNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("alias").InnerText + "." + xmlNode.GetNamedItem("name").InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine(attributeName);
                }
                else
                {
                    string attributeName = xmlNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine(attributeName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```